# Explict vs Implicit foreign key columns in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Occasionally, I come across a problem with the migrations generated by Entity Framework.

Typically, I have a model like this:

```
public class Account{
    int ID { get; set;}
    public virtual List<AccountInfo> AccountInfo { get; set;}
}

public class AccountInfo{
    int ID {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountID { get; set;}
    public virtual Account Account { get; set;}
}
```

Usually, this works just fine and generates the model as expected. Other times (usually when modifying an existing entity - I'm not sure I've ever seen this happen when creating a new entity), Entity Framework will try and generate a foreign key column for me. Using the previous example, it'd try and generate the following:

```
AccountInfo
     ID int
     Account_ID int
     AccountID int //Sometimes doesn't even do this

Account
     ID int
```

And then defines the foreign key on Account_ID.

I understand that if you do not define an explicit foreign key, Entity Framework will attempt to generate one for you (since your model may not need to have the foreign key because of navigation properties). However, since I explicitly configured the foreign key, I'd expect it to defer to my config.

Typically I just manually edit the migration so that it sets up the foreign key relationship on the correct property, but I assume this is not what I'm supposed to do. Am I missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing can really be said other than "that should work". I see no problems with the code you have here. The only thing I can recommend is to post the full code for a specific case where this has happened, i.e. literally copy and paste everything as you have it - don't just try to boil it down for us. Maybe then, someone can spot something.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error, I figured out the issue.

The entities I am working with are based on generated code, with partial classes for where I needed to extend them. I was extending them so they conform to a particular interface.

I had already created the Account and AccountInfo tables based on the generated code but adding in the correct foreign key relationship. To get them to conform to the proper interface, I did the following:

```
//Generated code
public partial class Account{
    public List<AccountInfo> GeneratedAccountInfos { get; set; }
    //other fields
}
//My code
public partial class Account : SomeAccountInterface{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    //Correct name to implement AccountInfos property of SomeAccountInterface
    public virtual List<AccountInfo> AccountInfos {get; set;} 
    List<SomeAccountInfoInterface> SomeAccountInterface.AccountInfos{
         get{ return AccountInfos; }
    }
}
public partial class AccountInfo{
     //some generated fiels
}
public partial class AccountInfo : SomeAccountInfoInterface{
    public virtual Account {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountID {get; set;}
}
```

The two properties with type List<AccountInfo> confused EntityFramework and also made it non-obvious what the issue was (I was also running into "Sequence contains more than one matching element" during migration creation, which pointed me in the right direction). Removing the AccountInfos property, while leaving the explicit interface definition (refering to GeneratedAccountInfos instead), fixed the issue.